# IntelliJ doesn't automatically update list of compiled libraries with maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I don't know why this is happening, in my other projects everything works perfectly. However I just started a new Maven Project from IntelliJ's project management and added the 'Web' framework. I've created my exploded artifact like I always do and everything works fine however when I update my `pom.xml` file with new libraries, IntelliJ just won't add the libraries in the artifact. I have to manually go to `Project Structure->Artifacts` and select all the new libraries from `Available Elements` and put them into the `WEB-INF\lib`. In my `External Libraries` tree everything gets updated normally when I change the `pom`. I just can't get intellij to add the new libraries (or remove the non existing ones for that matter) automatically like it always does. It's like it can't match the `pom.xml` with the project itself or something...

Answer (score 1):

The answer probably is that indeed it couldn't match the project with the `pom.xml` file and that is because I was missing the `<packaging>war</packaging>` tag on top. Once I put it in there intellij automatically generated artifacts with all the correct files.